# Static classes for a singular global instance

Tags: php, singleton, static-methods

In PHP, I'm developing an app that needs a singular instance to store and share data. I also have a couple of static classes that need to get and modify the data within the instance.

I would like to avoid global variables if it can be done, but I really don't know how to make the static classes and their methods access the instance.

Or is it a good idea to have one global instance as a global variable

```
$app = new App;
```

and then the static classes can use that global variable?

```
class Util {
  public static function method() {
    global $app;
    $app->property = 'something new';
  }
}
```

It seems like not the best idea. But without using singletons, I really don't see another way. I've also looked at dependency injection, but I couldn't find a way to make them work with static classes.

EDIT: I might not articulate myself clearly. It's not for saving data as a cache. It's runtime data.

Comment: Store and share data? It's not the responsibility of variable. You could save your shared data in cache or database.

Comment: You don't need static classes if you use dependency injection. Try to avoid static access, it's generally an anti-pattern.

Comment: I might not articulate myself clearly. It's not for saving data as a cache. It's runtime data.